# Amazon EMR - application list for specific EMR release?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I need to get the list of application for a specific Amazon EMR release. Is there any api available in AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon EMR applications are *not* available via API, but they are listed in the **documentation**, such as:

[image: Amazon EMR release apps]
<sub>(source: [amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/images/emr-5.17.0.png))</sub>

See:

- [About Amazon EMR Releases - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-components.html):
- [Amazon EMR 5.x Release Versions - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html)

Comment: To add to John's correct answer. You can see what hadoop applications are installed in a running cluster via CLI: `aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id j-ABCDEFGHIJKLM` or Boto3 API: `describe_cluster()`